# reach docker over remote using SSHTunnelForwarder

Tags: python, docker, ssh-tunnel

Im still new to docker and im trying to do somthing like this:

```
from sshtunnel import  SSHTunnelForwarder    
import docker

server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    'didi',
    ssh_username="george",
    ssh_password="ice",
    remote_bind_address=('192.168.56.103',22),
    local_bind_address =('unix:///var/run/docker.sock')
)

server.start()    
print(server.local_bind_port)    
client = docker.from_env()   
server.stop()
```

im getting the ValueError: Platform does not support UNIX domain sockets. and at the same time i didnt find a "secure" way to let the docker listen on a local port.

Does anyone know a simple workaround to resolve this? Thanx

Comment: Are you trying to grant the *remote* server access to your *local* docker? Or the other way around? Also, you seem to be using `22` as the port in your `remote_bind_address` which isn't going go to work...port 22 is used by `ssh` and will already be in use.

Comment: the other way around. i mean im trying to reach the docker, which is on another machine.

Comment: ('didi' => 192.168.56.103',22) is the machine, where the docker is on. i want to reach it over ssh. whenever im taking away local_bind_address, im being able to access the machine over ssh but im not finding a way how to start docker then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to reach Docker on a remote machine, you would need to forward a port on your *local* machine to the Docker socket on the remote machine. You can do this using an `ssh` command line like this:

```
ssh -L 4321:/var/run/docker.sock 192.168.56.103
```

As long as that connection is active, you can access Docker on local port 4321:

```
docker -H tcp://localhost:4321 ps
```

Unfortunately, the `sshtunnel` package does not support forwarding access to a remote Unix socket like this (see the [api documentation](https://sshtunnel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#api) for the `local_bind_address` and `remote_bind_address` options).

But you're in luck! You don't need to manually set up this sort of port forwarding; Docker is able to connect to a remote host via ssh all by itself by setting your `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable to an `ssh` url:

```
$ export DOCKER_HOST=ssh://192.168.56.103
$ python
Python 3.9.0 (default, Oct  6 2020, 00:00:00)
[GCC 10.2.1 20200826 (Red Hat 10.2.1-3)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> c = docker.from_env()
>>> info = c.info()
>>> info['ServerVersion']
'19.03.13'
```